# Backbone.js Node.js Accessing model on the server

Tags: node.js, backbone.js

Backbone.js with Mongoose/Express.

Im having the hardest time understanding how to communicate with the db and model on the server. Honestly I dont understand the relationship of the model and server. Does the model on the client sync with the model on the server? Is there even a model on the server? Current there is populated data in MongoDB and all Im trying to do is to get fetch() to work. Any help will be great. I'm trying to avoid using RESTful calls when Backbone already does all this.

```
// CLIENT
// Lobby.js

(function($){

    var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');

    var App = Backbone.Router.extend({
        routes: {
            '': 'lobby'
        },
        lobby: function () {
            var collection  = new Collection();
            var listView = new MatchListView(collection);

            collection.fetch();

            collection.fetch({success: function(){
                console.log("Fetch Success"); // => 2 (collection have been populated)
            }});
        }
    });

    var Model = Backbone.Model.extend();

    /**
    * Collection - bound to the server 
    * matchListView is listening for event changes
    */
    var Collection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        url: 'lobby',
        socket:socket,
        model: Model,
        initialize: function(Collection){
            _.bindAll(this, 'addOne', 'removeOne', 'removeOne');

            this.ioBind('createMatch', this.addOne, this);
            this.ioBind('removeMatch', this.removeOne, this);
        },
        addOne: function(data) {
            this.add({id:data._id});
        },
        removeOne: function(data) {
            console.log('remove match ' + data._id);
            this.remove({id:data._id});
        }
    });

    /**
    * View - bount to collection
    * listening for changes to collection 'add' and 'remove'
    */  
    var MatchListView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: $('body'),
        urlRoot: 'lobby',
        socket:socket,
        events: { 
            'click #create': 'createMatch'
        },    
        initialize: function(Collection){
            _.bindAll(this, 'render', 'renderCollection','addOne', 'removeOne', 'createMatch');

            this.collectionView = Collection;
            this.collectionView.bind('add', this.addOne);
            this.collectionView.bind('remove', this.removeOne);

            this._viewPointers = {}; // make sure we're starting over
            this.render();
        },
        render: function(){
            ...
        }
    });


    $(document).ready(function () 
    {
        //  create a new app and trigger the router.
        window.app = new App();
        Backbone.history.start();
    });

})(jQuery);
```

The above page lives at /lobby. The mongoDB on the server and it's schema lives at /mongo

```
//SERVER
// Mongo.js

 /**
* Mongol Database
*/
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var db = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost:27017/test');
//var db = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://nodejitsu_cpiv:es7te3ognihsibnii3a7ekdfu3@ds043927.mongolab.com:43927/nodejitsu_cpiv_nodejitsudb7525674102');
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', function callback () 
{
    console.log("connected to database tester");
});

/* ====================
// Lobby 
// =================== */
var schema = mongoose.Schema,
    ObjectId = schema.ObjectId;

var lobbySchema = new schema({
    status:Number,
    sockets: [{ id:String, team:Number}],
    player1:{id:Number},
    player2:{id:Number}
});


// Collection
var Lobby = db.model('lobby', lobbySchema);
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a way to think of it.

A model represents a data record with a more-or-less consistent schema (`status`, `sockets`, etc in your case). These records live canonically inside your MongoDB. Mongoose gives you a convenient way to create them, query for them, update them, and delete them from your server code in node.js. So on the server side, the data lives off in MongoDB and the Mongoose Schemas and Models you define are how you interact with and manipulate that data.

In the browser, you have the same **concept** of models representing data records, but you use Backbone to create them, query them, update them, and delete them. And instead of MongoDB, from the brower's perspective, the canonical data records exist on the other of end REST API calls, which backbone will help you make.

Now, the mapping of Mongoose models on the server to Backbone models on the client is not automatic. It's just a recommended architecture. You have to wire up your code with URLs and attributes appropriately to make things more or less match up as appropriate. Some discrepancies are OK, like having a `bcryptedPassword` field on your User model on the server but never sending that property to the browser since it is unnecessary and insecure to do so.

A few quick points on your code excerpts.

You are calling `fetch()` twice for no reason. You are also using `this.collectionView.bind('add', this.addOne);` where you want `this.collectionView.on('add', this.addOne);`. `bind` is for fixing the `this` context of methods. `on/off` are for registering event handlers.